# HelpNDoc script - method GetTagsAssociatedWithTopic

Tags: pascalscript, helpndoc

> Method `GetTagsAssociatedWithTopic` Unknown

I'm fairly new to HelpNDoc (working on an old version - 5).

From an existing script ( `ExportHelpIdsandContexts.hnd.pas` , provided with the installation ) I'm trying to get a list of the tags linked with each topic.

I thought `HndTags.GetTagsAssociatedWithTopic(aTopicId)` would get me through my task but if I try to build I get an error :

> identifient non déclaré `GetTagsAssociatedWithTopic` .

I was hoping to get a file with (Topic Caption | Help ID | Help Context | Tags)

```pascal
aList.Add(Format('%s | %s | %d | %s', [
        HndTopics.GetTopicCaption(aTopicId),
        HndTopics.GetTopicHelpId(aTopicId),
        HndTopics.GetTopicHelpContext(aTopicId),
        HndTags.GetTagsAssociatedWithTopic(aTopicId)
      ]));
```

got me the error described in the previous section.

I was thinking about the returned type of the function and tried to find a way to cast the returned `TStringList` into a `String`, but couldn't do it.

---

Add on
Thanks for your answer. I dug up a little more still have a problem with `TSTringDynArray`.

If i dont define it, the error is "unknown type".
Thanks to [FreePascal](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/types/tstringdynarray.html) i found out how it is supposed to be defined.

But of i define it, i get an erreur "Record required" for the following line

```
aTags:=HndTopicsTags.GetTagsAssociatedWithTopic(aTopicId);
```

So, i think i should have not "re"defined the TStringDynArray but i can't find out why it's not recognised by itself.

Answer (score 2):

This code seems to have multiple problems:

1. According to [HelpNDoc's API documentation](https://www.helpndoc.com/documentation/html/HelpNDocAPImethods.html), the `GetTagsAssociatedWithTopic` method is part of the `HndTopicsTags` object. So `HndTags.GetTagsAssociatedWithTopic` is wrong and should be replaced with `HndTopicsTags.GetTagsAssociatedWithTopic`
2. `HndTopicsTags.GetTagsAssociatedWithTopic` returns a `TStringDynArray` which is an array of string. It can't be used in the Format method using the `%s` placeholder. Instead, you should use a loop (`for`, `while` or `repeat`) to iterate over its items.

Answer (score 1):

So, I finally managed to get the script to work.

1. I needed to redefine

```pascal
type 
    TStringDynArray = array of String;
```

2. Stop mixing arrays and lists function

```pascal
for i:= low(aTags) to high(aTags) do
begin
    aTagsString:= aTagsString + ' | ' + aTags[i];
end;
```